# UIDatePicker min and max date not changing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm using Xcode 8.0 and building on iOS 10 with Swift 3.

I have UIDatePicker in my view controller, connected as an outlet :

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
```

I'm trying to set maximum and minimum dates for it. The code I'm using :

```
self.datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
self.datePicker.maximumDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*24*365)
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
```

is not working - date picker can go infinitely back and forward in time.

Question is - what am I missing here?

Comment: Where do you set these restrictions? (`init`, `viewDidLoad` etc.)

Comment: I have same issue.  After setting the minimumDate and maximumDate, reading those values back from the datePicker returns null (and the datePicker exists).  Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately suffered the same issue literally yesterday and after searching SO couldn't find a solution. I came up with my own implementation of max/min date to use in place of the built in one, it's not ideal, but it works.

```
func datePickerDidChangeDate(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let maxDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*24*365)
    let minDate = Date()

    if sender.date.compare(minDate) == .orderedAscending || sender.date.compare(maxDate) == .orderedDescending {
        // Date is invalid
        sender.setDate(Date()) // Set selected date to now.
        return
    }
}
```

Also note doing the whole `60*60*24*365` is a bad idea and you should instead use `NSCalendar.dateByAddingComponents` but that is an entirely different question altogether.